# Increasing raster exent with Raster Calculator is modifying band range

Tags: raster-calculator, arcgis-pro

I have a TIFF with a single band 16bit signed. I used the Raster Calculator tool to extend its extent:

```
Con(IsNull("mytif.tif"), 1, "mytif.tif")
```

Using ArcGIS Pro 2.0.0 I set the environment to the extent "As Specified Below" and the Snap Raster to the original TIFF (so that the cells align) and set the cell size to that of the original TIFF as well.

The original TIFF band has a range from 1 to 2487, the output raster from the tool has -132 to 2684.

Why are the values changing and how can I change them back to their correct scale (the represent elevation data at a specific resolution)?